# Passing onclick event into template literals without global function

Tags: javascript, template-literals

I've been working on adding onclick event in template literals with plain javascript (without jquery only javascript). As you can see the result html knows that onclick event on each div has function which will alert as I click but when I click, it didn't respond. It seems like suppose to work but somehow it is not working.

I got lots of help from Stackoverflow but most of the anwser was using global function. but I don't personally want to use global function since sometimes it cause some trouble.

so how can I actually pass the function into onclick event by using template literals?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="ul"></div>
    </body>
    <script src="/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

index.js

```
function test() {
    const list = [
        { number: 1, check: () => alert("1") },
        { number: 2, check: () => alert("2") },
        { number: 3, check: () => alert("3") },
    ];
    const $list = list.reduce((acc, item) =>
        acc + `<div onclick='${item.check}'>${item.number}</div>`,""
    );
    const $ul = document.querySelector("#ul");
    $ul.innerHTML = $list;
}
test();
```

result
[image]

Comment: Ok, so the immediate question would be, why do you need an arrow function in an onclick inline attribute?

Comment: And secondly, from your logic, it looks like you are trying to stick an actual function into that inline binding.  That's probably the main issue.  Inline bindings like this, are text values, not methods.  They will be parsed and evaluated as methods, but they are not methods.  They are text in the html.

Comment: Instead of building the DOM via HTML strings, create actual DOM elements.

Comment: Also, just going off of the screenshot, the attributes have a syntax issue with the `"` in the alerts conflicting with the `"` for the attribute.

Comment: Thank you for comments. I was just curious I could make react-like code with template literals. Like you said Creating actual dom will works but it is kind of experiment. And I actually saw the syntax error with “ in alerts earlier so I switch it to single quote and it doesnt throw error but browser display it as diuble quote somehow.

Comment: The reason why I use the arrow function is that when I use just function alone like alert then it execute alert when it create dom. So i thought it works like method but using arrow function didnt now work that way. Like you said it treat it like a string not method. Assuming there is no way I can call function with template literals?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building the DOM via HTML strings, create actual DOM elements.

```
const $ul = document.querySelector("#ul");
for (const item of list) {
  const element = document.createElement('div');
  element.textContent = item.number;
  element.onclick = item.check;
  $ul.appendChild(element);
}
```